# Remove lines of text that end in "/"

Tags: linux, text-processing, rsync, cp

I am using rsync to generate a list of files that have changed and then using that list to upload the files to s3:

```
rsync -av somefiles/ someotherfiles/ > list.txt


while read F  ; do
        echo $F
        aws s3 cp $lcDir/$F s3://durktest/blender/$F
done <list.txt
```

Example of what's in the list

```
swresample-2.dll
swscale-4.dll
tahoe.log
ucrtbase.dll
vcomp140.dll
vcruntime140.dll
2.78/
2.78/config/
2.78/config/bookmarks.txt
2.78/config/recent-files.txt
2.78/config/userpref.blend
2.78/datafiles/
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/config.ocio
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_desat65cube.spi3d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_false_color.spi3d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_0-35_1-30.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_0-48_1-09.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_0-60_1-04.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_0-70_1-03.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_0-85_1-011.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_0.99_1-0075.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic/filmic_to_1.20_1-00.spi1d
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/luts/
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/luts/aces_to_xyz.spimtx
2.78/datafiles/colormanagement/luts/adx_adx10_to_cdd.spimtx
```

Is there any better way to do this besides just using a fuse driver and doing rsync directly to s3?

Comment: I suppose, your `somefiles/ someotherfiles/` means directory names. Do you want to just ignore subdirectories from copying?

Comment: I'd guess that would break on directory and file names containing line breaks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a better way to do this : use `aws s3 sync`

Example

```
aws s3 sync somefiles/ s3://durktest/blender
```

read [AWS CLI Command Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) for more

Answer (score 7):

To remove lines ending in `/`, just use `sed`:

```
sed '/\/$/d'
```

That copies from standard input to standard output, deleting lines that end in `/`. Or use `grep`:

```
grep -v '/$'
```

Probably lots of other ways.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
grep -v '/$' list.txt |
  xargs -rd '\n' -I@FILE@ aws s3 cp "$lcDir/@FILE@" s3://durktest/blender/@FILE@
```

(assuming `$lcDir` doesn't contain `@FILE@`)

Note that you have a few issues in your code, in that:

- You called `read` without `-r` and without emptying `$IFS`
- you forgot to quote `$lcDir` and `$F`
- you used `echo`
- in any case, you'll have problems with filenames containing newline characters with that approach.

If you did want to use a loop, you could do:

```
(
  ret=0
  while IFS= read -r F <&3; do
    case $F in
      (*/) ;;
      (*)
        printf '%s\n' "$F"
        aws s3 cp "$lcDir/$F" "s3://durktest/blender/$F" || ret=$?;;
    esac
  done 3< list.txt
  exit "$ret"
)
```

You may also want to consider `duplicity` which AFAIK supports Amazon s3 as a backend.

Comment: what is this `@FILE@`?

Comment: @cat, It's a placeholder: xargs reads in a line (filename) at a time, replaces the placeholder in the command with the line, and executes it.